# Unspecified error with a file upload loop

Tags: php, forms, post, file-upload

I'm using a form and a loop to upload multiple image files directly to the file server, but I'm getting a false result with the move_uploaded_file function.

Upload Form:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <form action='uploadform.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            Select the files you would like to upload.
            <input type='file' name='fileToUpload[]' id='fileToUpload' mozdirectory webkitdirectory directory multiple />
            <input type='submit' value='Upload Image' name='submit'>
        </form><br>
    The files will be uploaded to a folder named '".$_SESSION['filename']."'.<br>
    </p>
</body>
```

Multiple file uploading loop (uploadform.php:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $i => $name) {
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if (strlen($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                echo basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
            } 
            else {
                echo "Error! File basename: ".basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i])."<br>";
            }
            $count++;
        }

    }

}
```

When uploading one or multiple files with the form, it goes to the else statement echoing the "ERROR" string.
The Apache Error Log comes up blank, so I have no clue what's wrong with the code.

I tried echoing the variables used in the loop ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i], $target_file and $imageFileType) but these seem to be fine.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `ftp`?

Comment: `If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. ` [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Have you tried to debug your code step by step ?

Comment: Furhtermore, why do you use `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]` and not `$name` inside your foreach-loop ? Shouldn't be this the same ?

Comment: When moving files to their final destination you have to use their `tmp_name` inside the `$_FILES` super global. That is the name they are stored under temporary...

Comment: And a side note: using a "file name extension" as means to find out the type of a file does not make any sense at all. Example: a pdf document still is a pdf document even when called "damn.exe"...

Comment: I'm very inexperienced in PHP, didn't realise that $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i] would be the same as $name.

Comment: After changing `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]` to `$name` to reduce clutter and changing the variable from `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]` to `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]` in the loop the problem is solved. I didn't know where the name was saved exactly, so I just assumed it'd be named the same as the input field in the form. Thanks!

Comment: Err, I'm a bit inexperienced with stackoverflow as well: Is there a way to mark arkascha's comment as the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]` variable was not the one that the loop was supposed to use.

By changing all instances of `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]` to `$name` (which is `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]`) the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I would put entire foreach loop in try-catch block and see what, if any Exception occurs:

```
try{
     // your foreach loop here:
    }
catch(\Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```